# Stateful function pipeline

Tags: scala, functional-programming, closures, pipeline, purely-functional

The code explains itself.

```
val s = Seq(1,1,1)
val res: Seq[Int] = s.map(...)
                     .check(count how many 1s, if > 2 throw Exception)
                     .map(...)
```

I am searching the simple solution to this `check` function .

- I can use `map` and `closure` to count and throw, but I want pure function.
- I can use `filter` and `size` or `reduce`, but it return a value and not resumable with following maps.

How do I make a **pure** and **stateful** checking-pipe to the pipeline ?

Comment: Write a simple function, which will take whole collection as input, do the check inside it using reduce, and will return Some(collection) if check was ok, and None otherwise. Then it will be pure. You can inject check as lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to pattern match, so check would become:

```
> Seq(1, 1) match {
    case ls if (ls.count(_ == 1) <= 2) => ls
    case _ => throw new Exception("oh no!")
  }
List(1, 1): Seq[Int]


> Seq(1, 1, 1) match {
    case ls if (ls.count(_ == 1) <= 2) => ls
    case _ => throw new Exception("oh no!")
  }
java.lang.Exception: oh no!
  $.<init>(Main.scala:177)
  $.<clinit>(Main.scala:-1)
```

It may be preferable to return an Option type (instead of throwing):

```
> Seq(1, 1, 1) match {
    case ss if (ss.count(_ == 1) <= 2) => Option(ss)
    case _ => None
  }
None: Option[Seq[Int]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Throwing an exception is arguably not pure.  If you instead were using a monadic form of error handling, you'd do something like this:

```
Option(s.map(foo)).
  filter(m => m.count(_ == 1) < 2).
  map{ s =>
    s.map(bar)
     .filter(baz)
     ...
  }
```

As it is, if you want to compose it within the pipeline, and you don't want to add extra parentheses as is necessary with `match`, you can use the commonly-enriched `tap` method:

```
implicit class TapAnything[A](private val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def tap[U](f: A => U): A = { f(a); a }
}
```

Now you can

```
s.map(...)
 .tap(self => if (self.count(_ == 1) > 1) throw new Exception)
 .map(...)
 ...
```

(note: the `private val` + `extends AnyVal` stuff is just to indicate to the compiler that it's supposed to try to avoid creating an extra object to make the call).

Comment: I guess you could make a similar `tapOption` instead of throwing :) (great answer!)

Comment: @AndyHayden - It's not really a tap if it's changing the type.  Otherwise it's a pipe, usually written `|>` and done in general, but you could of course do `s |> {x => if (x.count(_ == 1) < 2) Some(x) else None}` inline.  (Possibly needing a `.` after the `s` to get the precedence of everything correct.)  But, yes, one can make a validating analog (maybe `optionIf` would be a better name than `tapOption`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass along an error message without throwing an exception, a good candidate would be [`Either[A, B]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M4/scala/util/Either.html). This would require some more work (working with `left` or `right` operands) down the pipeline, but allows you to pass a long a more descriptive error message, where for example, `Option[T]` can't convey:

```
val x = Seq(1,1,0)
        .map(_ * 3)
        .map(i => if (i > 2) Right(i) else Left("Was smaller than 2"))
        .map(_.right.map(_ * 3))

x.foreach {
  case Right(i) => println("Yay, right")
  case Left(error) => println(error)
}
```

---

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  val x = Seq(1,1,0)
    .map(_ * 3)
    .map(i => if (i > 2) Right(i) else Left("Was smaller than 2"))
    .map(_.right.map(_ * 3))

  x.foreach {
    case Right(i) => println("Yay, right")
    case Left(error) => println(error)
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

Yay, right
Yay, right
Was smaller than 2
```

This can be slightly inconvenient as `Either` is unbiased, but it does allow you to flow the behavior.

Comment: The convention is that `Right` is correct and `Left` is wrong, when using `Either` for error handling.